# Moq - Setting HttpResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to Mock a HttpResponse for a ConrollerContext object using MVC 4, Moq 4 and C# 4.5

My code is here:

```
var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();

context.SetupProperty(c => c.Response = response);
```

I have tried using `Setup().Returns()` and `SetupGet()` but I keep getting the following error:

> > "Property or Indexer 'System.Web.HttpContextBase.Response' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

I have tried Googling this and searching on this website, but I can't seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that I did not pass the correct object into the `Returns()` method. I should have passed the mock's `Object` property.

Here is the correct code:

```
var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();

context.Setup(c => c.Response).Returns(response.Object);
```

Answer (score 5):

For get-only properties, use `SetupGet(..)`, and specify a `.Returns(..)` clause with the return value to inject:

```
var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();

context.SetupGet(c => c.Response)
       .Returns(response.Object);
```